# Detect all template expressions not enclosed by curly braces

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a template string like so:

`'%album_artist%/%album%{ (%year%)}/{%track_number%. }%track_artist% - %title%'`

I want to find all variables, that are not optional, thus not enclosed by curly braces: `track_artist`, `title`, `album_artist` and `album` *but not* `track_number` and `year`.

Currently, my expression is `'(?<![{])%([A-Za-z_]+)%(?![}])'`, but that also matches `year`.

What do I have to change in order to have the regex not beeing confused by additional characters around the variable name or multiple variables inside the curly braces?

I use Python's `re`.

**Related Questions:**

- [A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324749/a-regex-to-detect-string-not-enclosed-in-double-quotes)
- [Regular Expression, match characters outside curly braces { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032016/regular-expression-match-characters-outside-curly-braces)
- [Regex to match keyword if not enclosed by curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056472/regex-to-match-keyword-if-not-enclosed-by-curly-braces)

Comment: What flavor/language are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP, you can use this pattern:

```
~{[^}]*+}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|%\w++%~i
```

Example:

```
preg_match_all('~{[^}]*+}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|%\w++%~i', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

If you use Python, you can do the same trick (ie: matching content in curly brackets before and then searching what you are looking for) with a capture group:

```
import re

mystr = r'%album_artist%/%album%{ (%year%)}/{%track_number%. }%track_artist% - %title%';
print filter(bool, re.findall(r'{[^}]*|(?i)%(\w+)%', mystr))
```

Notice:

You can try this other pattern which will stop the match at the last `%`  after an opening curly bracket (no sure that it is faster than the first):

```
print filter(bool, re.findall(r'{(?:[^}%]*%)*|(?i)%(\w+)%', mystr))
```

Comment: What's this `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` construct? I've never seen it, and RegexBuddy 4 doesn't know it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ahah! It's a PCRE feature. These verbs are designed for backtracking control. SKIP indicates that the previous subpattern can't success and FAIL forces the subpattern to fail (like `(?!)`). The goal is to avoid empty results unlike `\K`

Comment: Sadly Python `re` does not support PCRE very well.

Comment: @moi: I added a Python version.

Comment: Thanks for the python version! The second version does not work if multiple variables are enclosed by curly braces, like in `str = '%album_artist%/%album%{ (%year%)}/{%track_number%. }{%track_artist% - %title%}'`

Comment: BTW, `str` is a keyword ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an alternation and only do grouping over the branch that doesn't match curly braces. It will return results with blank strings that you can filter out, like:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'''%album_artist%/%album%{ (%year%)}/{%track_number%. }%track_artist% - %title%'''
>>> list(filter(lambda e: e.strip(), re.findall(r'\{[^}]*\}|%([^%]*)%', s)))
['album_artist', 'album', 'track_artist', 'title']
```

Comment: It works, thanks! However, it would be shorter to use `filter(bool,...)` like in Casimirs answer.